# Making for loop dynamic in xlsxwriter module

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I have the below loop statement that runs through 'report' object and updates value in an excel sheet as shown:

```
row = 1
col = 0

for e1, e2, e3 in report:
    worksheet1.write(row, col, e1, number_format)
    worksheet1.write(row, col + 1, e2, number_format)
    worksheet1.write(row, col + 2, e3, number_format)
    row += 1
```

As seen there are 3 columns that I am trying to update namely e1, e2 and e3. I am trying to see if I can make this for loop dynamic such that it can run through any number of columns without having to define it.

Could anyone advice on this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood, but wouldn't you be able to do this?

```
current_row = 1

for values in report:
    for idx, value in enumerate(values):
        worksheet1.write(current_row, idx, value, number_format)
    current_row += 1
```

Basically this doesn't specify e1, e2, e3 but writes the tuple to `values` and then a new `for` loop iterates over that tuple and is independent of the number of entries.